# Kusto | calculate percentage grouped by 2 columns

Tags: kql

I have a result set that look something similar to the table below and I extended with Percentage like so:

```
datatable (Code:string, App:string, Requests:long)
[
 "200", "tra", 63,
 "200", "api", 1036,
 "302", "web", 12,
 "200", "web", 219,
 "500", "web", 2,
 "404", "api", 18
]
| as T
| extend Percentage = round(100.0 * Requests / toscalar(T | summarize sum(Requests)), 2)
```

The problem is I really want the percentage to be calculated from the total of Requests of the Code by App rather than the grand total.

For example, for the App "api" where Code is "200", instead of 76.74% of the total, I want to express it as a percentage of just the "api" Code values, which would be 98.29% of the total Requests for App "api".

I haven't really tried anything that would be considered valid syntax.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `join` or `lookup` operators:

```
datatable (Code:string, App:string, Requests:long)
[
 "200", "tra", 63,
 "200", "api", 1036,
 "302", "web", 12,
 "200", "web", 219,
 "500", "web", 2,
 "404", "api", 18
]
| as T
| lookup ( T | summarize sum(Requests) by App ) on App
| extend Percentage = round(100.0 * Requests / sum_Requests, 2)
| project Code, App, Requests, Percentage
```

| Code | App | Requests | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | api | 1036 | 98.29 |
| 404 | api | 18 | 1.71 |
| 200 | tra | 63 | 100 |
| 302 | web | 12 | 5.15 |
| 200 | web | 219 | 93.99 |
| 500 | web | 2 | 0.86 |